# Guest VM with window OS failed to installed on ubuntu 22.04 host

Tags: 22.04, windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to create VM with window OS on ubuntu 22.04 host. My installation crashed with blue screen and the error is "system exception thread not handled". VM created successfully on ubuntu 20.04 using same ISO file.

1. Tried with SATA, SCSI, VIRTIO.
2. VIRTIO with latest virtio driver ISO for window.
3. Different version of machine type - pc-q35-6.2, pc-q35-4.2, q35
4. Different disk type RAW, QCOW2

**Following is my template xml file which I am using to create VM using "virsh". I am not sure what specific configuration is required on ubuntu 22.04 host**

````
<domain type='qemu'>
  <name>windows</name>
  <memory unit='KiB'>16777216</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>16777216</currentMemory>
  <memoryBacking>
    <locked/>
  </memoryBacking>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-6.2'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <cpu mode='host-model'/>
  <devices>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/windows.img' index='1'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/window_installer.iso' index='1'/>
     <target dev='sdb' bus='sata'/>
    </disk>
    <disk>
     ... # configuration for virtio-win iso
    </disk>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <driver iommu='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <driver iommu='on'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <driver iommu='on'/>
      <rom enabled='no'/>
    </interface>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='network' network='default'/>
    </graphics>
    <console type='pty'/>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <driver iommu='on' />
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>```
````